# Different Twiml for voicemail

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

we have a Windows service, that automatically send multiple voice calls for appointment reminders.

```
var call = CallResource.Create(
                    machineDetection: "DetectMessageEnd",
                    asyncAmd: "true",
                    twiml: new Twiml(message),
                    to: new PhoneNumber(toPhone),
                    from: new PhoneNumber(FromPhone));
```

The message used for the one above is dynamically generated using the Twiml below.

```
<Response>
  <Pause length="1"/>
  <Say voice="alice">Hello {name},</Say>
  <Pause length="1"/>
  <Say voice="alice">Your appointment is scheduled for {date} at {time}.</Say>
  <Pause length="1"/>
  <Gather timeout="3" numDigits="1" action="https://6f8137e0cb9a.ngrok.io/Voice/gather?aid=12345" method="GET">
    <Say voice="alice">To confirm this appointment press 1, to cancel press 2, or you may hang up.</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

It works fine, when the call is picked up, but if no answer then when it goes to voicemail. I want to send a different Twiml like the one below

```
<Response>
  <Pause length="1"/>
  <Say voice="alice">Hello {name},</Say>
  <Pause length="1"/>
  <Say voice="alice">Your appointment is scheduled for {date} at {time}.</Say>
  <Pause length="1"/>
  <Say voice="alice">To confirm or cancel this appointment call 18888888888.</Say>
</Response>
```

Is this even possible with Twilio ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

That is absolutely possible! In your original script it shows that you are using asyncAmd, which means that your initial message will start playing even as the machine detection goes on. If a machine is detected then the AMD will want to alert you of that.

To do that, you need to provide an [`asyncAmdStatusCallback` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection#asyncamdstatuscallback) to your outbound call that points to a URL that can receive a webhook when you get the result from the AMD.

That webhook will receive paramters including the `CallSid` and your `AccountSid` and most importantly the `AnsweredBy` parameter. When using `DetectMessageEnd` for your AMD, the `AnsweredBy` parameter could be any of "machine_end_beep", "machine_end_silence", "machine_end_other", "human", "fax" and "unknown".

For the machine results, if you want to leave a message you will now need to [update your call with new TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource).

```cs
var call = CallResource.Update(
    twiml: new Twiml(MACHINE_MESSAGE),
    pathSid: CALL_SID
);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Hi @Philnash, followed ur instructions, but now the answering machine has both the twiml, the end of the original twiml and the new one from the asyncAmdStatusCallback uri.  Is there a way, can we avoid the original one?

Comment: You can avoid starting the original TwiML by using synchronous AMD (set `asyncAmd` to `false`). That way you won't get the webhook callback until Twilio has worked out whether it is a human or a machine.

Comment: Hi @philnash, if I set the asyncAmd to false, it is not even going to the answering machine at all.  I even tried all combinations of machineDetection to "Enable" and "DetectMessageEnd" and also the machineDetectionTimeout to 59.

Comment: I think I wrote that a bit late at night so it didn't include all the details. When you do *synchronous AMD* you need to handle whether it is a machine or a human in your initial webhook and return different TwiML to each of them. *Asynchronous AMD* means you respond with TwiML and then adjust when you get the result later. If you turned `asyncAmd` to `false` did you also adjust your webhook?

Comment: Thanks @philnash, setting the asyncAmd to false worked on all carriers except one. 
 Ended up opening a ticket with Twilio, and they suggested to remove the pause length in the beginning of the Twiml and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Ah, awesome to hear it. Glad you got it sorted.